# React Referenced component is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a value down my component tree, I am using refs on my components to do that.
However, React keeps telling me `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`. Which means it cannot find a reference to my component, which is not the case:

```
<FormBox url = "api/skills" handleClose = {this.handleClose} ref = {(ref)=>{this.formbox = ref;}}/>
```

I am changing the state of formbox once the state of the container changes as seen below:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  this.formbox.setState({parent: this.state.parent});
}
```

What precisely am I doing wrong? what should I do to fix it?

**Edit:** Here's the whole file:

```
class ModalForm extends Component{

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      show: false,
      parent: 0
    };

  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.formbox.setState({parent: this.state.parent});
  }

  handleClose(event) {
    console.log("hiding");
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  handleShow(event) {
    console.log("showing");
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Add A Skill</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <FormBox url = "api/skills" handleClose = {this.handleClose} ref = {(ref)=>{this.formbox = ref;}}/>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @JoeClay No, I am not using a method, but a reference to a component. Besides, the solution to his issue did not work for me:
`Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined: this.formbox = this.formbox.bind(this);`

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Retracted the duplicate vote!

Comment: where is the componentDidUpdate written??

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: it is written in the parent component of FormBox. I'll post the whole file.

Comment: Are you not creating the property `formbox` in the class? e.g. `var formbox = null` above the constructor?

Comment: No, I have not done that..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69ecor2c/ your code works, so something else is there that we can't see

Comment: It seems with React 16 `componentDidUpdate()` is firing before the ref is resolved. I looked up the issue, it seems that would be the case if the component is not rendered. however this is a modal, and I must not be rendered in the beginning so I will try to think of a work around..

Answer (score 0):

You should [create the ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props, context);
  this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
  this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

  // Create ref instance
  this.formboxRef = React.createRef();

  this.state = {
    show: false,
    parent: 0
  };
}
```

And then attach the ref to your component in the render function:

```
<FormBox url="api/skills" handleClose={this.handleClose} ref={this.formboxRef}/>
```

Now you can use your current ref anywhere in your component context this way:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  this.formboxRef.current.setState({parent: this.state.parent});
}
```

Comment: I realized that there is a common issue with React 16 where `componentWillUpdate()` fires before refs are resolved if the component is not rendered (**ex.**: modals). That precisely was my issue since my code was written with React 15.6 and wasn't facing any issues before I moved everything to 16. Is this how you guarantee refs are resolved before lifecycle methods as of React 16?